# How to convert list data into Binary Search Tree(BST) with graph manner in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graphviz, pydot

I want to create a Binary Search Tree(BST) from list of data with graphical manner in python.I used the following code as

> import pydot
>
> from binarytree import build
>
> values = [3, 5, 2, 1, 4,14]
>
> tree = build(values)
>
> print(tree)
>
> print(tree.values)
>
> graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
>
> for i in tree.values:
>
> edge = pydot.Edge(i, i+1)
>
> graph.add_edge(edge)
>
> graph.write_png('example1_graph.png')

I got the output in python environment as

[image]

and in png format as

[image]

But I want the output as in binary tree format with graphical manner as follows

[image]

How can I convert the tree(code variable) values in to a graphical BST format? (Your answer may be using graphviz,matplotlib package also) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tree plotting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670280/tree-plotting-in-python)

Comment: Thanks.. The above mentioned link shows, how to draw the general trees.. but I want to draw the binary search tree in data structure subject with its rules(property).. if any packages is there in python means share with me.. thanks..

Comment: Can you highlight the differences? You have shown three completely different trees. How are they generated? Why should something like building the proper tree structure, output it in DOT format, and plot it through GraphViz not work?

Comment: Using the print(tree.values) code I got the first diagram output. But it is not in graphical manner.. So I used the graph.write_png('example1_graph.png') code to got second diagram. But it not follows the Binary tree rules(Actually I can't convert it). My expected output is the third diagram(green coloured) which I got it from online editor not in python code.. If I want the get the  third diagram(green coloured), what python code am I want to use?(It should follows binary tree rules as well as in graphical manner).

Comment: Well, your code looks flawed: why do you build edges for the second graph between a value and the next larger integer, while your first graph has completely other edges? The third (green) graph has a third set of edges - which one is the proper set?

Comment: Hi  Nico Haase.. please forget my code.. I searched lot of codes, but I couldn't find the exact one.. So I used that code and I know it may not be correct..  If I give a list of input values like [3,2,5,1,4,14] I want to get the third diagram(green coloured) which  follows binary tree rules and it is in the form of graphical manner.. I want to get the third diagram(green coloured) like output using python code.. Guide me.. Thanks..

Comment: Please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586085/difference-between-binary-search-and-binary-search-tree for binary search tree rules.. Thanks..

Comment: Please don't unneccessarily link to other questions. I think the main problem is that you should import `bst` rather than `build` - have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks Nico Haase for your patience response yet now.. Now I got some basic idea based on your guideline.. I will update myself.. thanks..